# Backbone/Underscore sortBy is not sorting collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a list of users (six to be exact) in a collection with 'firstname', 'lastname' properties. Doing a fetch, the comparator below sorts them by 'firstname', and it works fine.

```
comparator : function (user) {
  return user.get("firstname").toLowerCase();
}
```

But if I try to sort the collection later, by a different value i.e. 'lastname', it doesn't work. The order stays the same.

```
this.collection.sortBy(function(user) {
  return user.get("lastname").toLowerCase();
});
```

What am i doing wrong?

**Update**

---

So the data returned from sortBy IS sorted but that doesn't help me really as my view is linked to the collection. If i reset the collection and add the sorted array back to the collection it's comparator does it's job and sorts it back into 'firstname' order.

```
var sorted = this.collection.sortBy(function(user) {
  return user.get("lastname").toLowerCase();
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `sortBy` function does not sort the objects in the current collection. It returns a sorted collection:

```
var sortedCollection = this.collection.sortBy(function(user){
  return user.get("lastname").toLowerCase();
});
```

Now you can use `sortedCollection` and it will be sorted correctly.

Comment: isn't that comparator function should return integer?

Comment: Note that this returns a list and not a collection.  Not a huge deal but worth mentioning.

Answer (score 13):

To respond to your update:

If you're wanting to change the order that the collection is sorted in for use by it's corresponding view then you could just update the `comparator` and then call `sort` to get the model re-sorted.  This will then fire a `sort` event which your view can listen for and update itself accordingly.

```
this.collection.comparator = function (user) {
  return user.get("firstname").toLowerCase();
};

this.collection.sort();
```

Comment: This is definitely the best answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Underscore's `sortBy` which Backbone uses, *returns* the sorted collection not sort it in place...
To illustrate:

```
var flinstones = [{first: 'Baby', last: 'Puss'}, {first: 'Fred', last: 'Flinstone'}];
var sorted = _.sortBy(flinstones, function (character) { return character.last ; });
console.log(sorted);
console.log(flinstones);
```