# Backbone sort collection array

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have an app in backbone and underscore.
I have already seen this questions but I haven'0t solved my problem because is a little bit different:
[Sorting Backbone Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801660/sorting-backbone-collections)
[Backbone/Underscore sortBy is not sorting collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803378/backbone-underscore-sortby-is-not-sorting-collection)

My problem is: I have a collection into a view and I want to sort it by the field order and after print this collection into the template.

I have tried this but doesn't work with underscore:

```
this.hotels.models = _(this.hotels.models).sortBy("order");
$(this.el).html(this.template({hotels: this.hotels.models}));
```

How can I sort my collection(model) and after print it inot template?
My code doesn't sort my array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `models` array is an array of Model objects, the attributes of which are stored in `model.attributes`. Wrapping the array and calling `sortBy` assumes the objects being sorted are plain objects, and the attribute directly accessible as `model.{attribute}`.

To get it to do what you want you can pass `sortBy` a comparator function that `get`s the attribute you want:

```
this.hotels.models = _(this.hotels.models).sortBy(function(model) {
    return model.get("order");
});
```

However this is what Backbone already does in the Collection class. To use the built-in comparator you can simply set the Collection's `comparator` attribute to the name of the Model attribute by which you want to sort.

Example:

```
this.hotels.comparator = "order";
this.hotels.sort();
$(this.el).html(this.template({hotels: this.hotels.models}));
```

Comment: Thanks this solve the problem, and sincerly I cannot understand how to use comparator... uhm can you make a simple example? +1 for the answer

Comment: Thanks! Clean solution.